# How do I pass a var from within a dispatch_sync block?

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety, dispatch

I need to extract a NSData item from within a block of a dispatch_sync().

Specifically, I can't do a 'return data' in mid block due to a compiler error:

> Incompatible block pointer types passing 'NSData *(^)(void)' to
>   parameter of type 'dispatch_block_t' (aka 'void (^)(void)')

The error occurs here:

> if (data)return data; // data is present in memory cache

```
- (NSData  *)dataForFile:(NSString *)fileName {
    __block NSData *data;
    // ... having problem with 'data' var within dispatch_sync
    dispatch_sync(serialQueue, ^{
        data = [_memoryCache objectForKey:fileName];
        if (data)return data; // data is present in memory cache

        NSString *archivePath = [_cacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:archivePath];

        if (data) {
            [self cacheData:data toFile:fileName]; // put the recently accessed data to memory cache
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

...should I put a return type vs a (void) on the block?  Or need it be re-engineered?
One solution is to replace the dispatch with a @synchronized().

**Question:** is it possible to break out of a block & return during a dispatch_sync()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask yourself where the return value would go. You've got no `<var> = dispatch_sync(...)`, so you don't expect a result, which is good as `dispatch_sync` doesn't return one!

`dispatch_sync` takes a block with return type of `void` - your block cannot return a value with `return`. However a block can assign to captured local variables which have the `__block` attribute - just as your `data` variable does, and you do assign to that within your block. You don't need to assign to `data` *and* return it, which seems to be what you are trying to do.

At a guess what you want is:

```
dispatch_sync(serialQueue, ^{
    data = [_memoryCache objectForKey:fileName];
    if (!data) // data is NOT present in memory cache
    {
        NSString *archivePath = [_cacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:archivePath];

        if (data) {
            [self cacheData:data toFile:fileName]; // put the recently accessed data to memory cache
        }
    }
});
```

HTH